# Solr searching within a dictionary file

Tags: search, dictionary, solr

I was wondering if there is something out of the box from Solr which would allow me to search within a dictinary file (containing words and phrases) to returning all the phrases that contains my search terms.

For example, my dictionary file could have:

```
red car
blue bike
big bike tires
```

When I search 'bike', I expect to see

```
blue bike
big bike tires
```

And when I search 'big tires', i expect to see

```
big bike tires
```

Is there anything from Solr that could support this? I was looking into the SpellCheckComponent but it would only support prefix searches.

Basically, I would like to achieve solr searches (token searching) but against a dictionary file (this same file would also be used for autosuggest).

Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store such phrases in the index itself? The schema can be:

```
type: suggest_phrase #other types are product or review_article
phrase: big bike tires
```

So your search for `big tires` would be:

```
..fq=type:suggest_phrase&q=phrase:big tires
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This would work, but I had concern, that my existing schema has several fields for product information. If I were to add these phrases to the index itself, then this document entry would not need to populate the other 'product' related fields since the phrase type is a 'suggest_phrase'. Is this okay? Is it better to just have a brand new schema for the phrases on its own (running on a separate core), or is it better to incorporate them into the existing schema?

Comment: I would incorporate them into the existing schema for simplicity. We also use document types; both with fields that are specific to each type as well as common fields (like creation date).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a general rule as to when different document types should be kept within the same schema vs being separated into different schemas.  taking into consideration performance (not sure about how performance would be impacted using fq vs separate core) or maybe the overlapping of fields from different document types.. what if there is little to no overlap between the fields of different document type; does this mean we should use a different schema altogether even though the business domain is related (ie. products, review_article).

Comment: Please test for yourself with dummy documents and see how many X million documents does performance becomes unacceptable. If you need more help, ask a new question.